# Error start Session

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Fatal error: Call to a member function start() on boolean in /media/Work/Server/konzeptual.local/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 493

Line 493:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => $this->_sessionNamespace))->start();
```

Screenshot:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wkwk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', ....)  === false  !

Try this in a separate file... (Like a PhpUnit Test)

```
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
var_export(['Object?' => is_object(Mage::getSingleton('core/session'))]);
```

Now look if you get a object. Then, if it's a `NO` just look what name Magento is trying to load, like: "Amasty_CrappyModule/session". Then your problem is a re-write that can't be found. If it's looking for: Mage_Core_Model_Session then check the file for existence.

Comment: Also: Flush cache and turn off compilation.

Comment: array ( 'Object?' => false, ) - in test

Cache off, Compilation off

Comment: Perfect this is what we expected. Thus we understand the message of the exception clearly. Now the next test will reveal witch classname Magento actually tries to load given the name 'core/session'.  Now add the next line to the var_export in the test: `'classname?' => Mage::getConfig()->getModelClassName('core/session')`. If it's `Mage_Core_Model_Session` check if the file exists and can be loaded.